# How does horizontal scaling work if you only have a monolith database?

Tags: database, mongodb, web, mern, horizontal-scaling

Let's take a typical APP built upon a typical tech stack, MERN = MongoDB, Express, React, and Node.

Let's suppose that my user base grows. I have decided to horizontally scale by distributing multiple containers of my backend Node server across multiple machines.

But if the MongoDB database is still just a monolith living on one machine, all of these parallely running Node instances will still have to query this one MongoDB instance, and so will have to queue?

Comment: If a single databas is not enough for the load you expect then you may need to re-architecture/re-design your entire app using microservices.